# Do I have to consider for loops in condition coverage?

Tags: testing, conditional-statements, code-coverage

often, for-loops consist of conditions which are dependant of function parameters, for example for(a = 1; a < fun_par; a++). So to me, it sounds logical to include those decisions in the condition coverage. Am I wrong with this assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, As there is a condition on which execution of particular block of code is depended, for loops need to be considered in condition coverage.